# How do I send a notification to a user in Teams via the Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a Bot created with v4 of the [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable). I can successfully use this bot in the "Test in Web Chat" portion in the Azure Portal. I can also successfully use this bot in an app that I've created in Microsoft Teams. I now want to send a notification from the "Test in Web Chat" piece to a specific user in Teams. For example, in the "Test in Web Chat" piece, I'd like to enter

```
Hello someuser@mytenant.com
```

When this is sent via the "Test in Web Chat" piece, I'd like to show "Hello" in Microsoft Teams to only `someuser@mytenant.com`. I have successfully tokenized the string from the "Test in Web Chat". Thus, I know what I want to send, and who I want to send it to. However, I do not know how to actually send it.

Currently, I have the following in my bot:

```
public class EchoBot : ActivityHandler
{
  private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> _conversationReferences;

  public EchoBot(ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConversationReference> conversationReferences)
  {
    _conversationReferences = conversationReferencs;
  }

  private void AddConversationReference(Activity activity)
  {
    var reference = activity.GetConversationReference();
    _conversationReferences.AddOrUpdate(reference.User.Id, reference, (key, newValue) => reference);
  }

  protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    AddConversationReference(context.Activity as Activity);

    var parameters = GetParameters();  // Parses context.Activity.Text;

    // Send a message to the target (i.e. someuser@mytenant.com)
    var connection = new Microsoft.Bot.Connector.ConnectorClient(new Uri(context.Activity.ServiceUrl));
    var tenant = context.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>().Tenant;
    // how do I send the message to parameters.Target?

    // Confirm message was sent to the sender
    var confirmation = $"Message was sent to {parameters.Target}.";
    await context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(confirmation));
  }
}
```

I've reviewed how to [send proactive notifications to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). However, I've been unsuccessful in a) getting the user specified in `parameters.Target` and b) sending a notification to that user. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need to map `user@email.com` to their Teams userId (maybe with a static dictionary), which is in the format of:

```
29:1I9Is_Sx0O-Iy2rQ7Xz1lcaPKlO9eqmBRTBuW6XzXXXXXXXXMij8BVMdBcL9L_RwWNJyAHFQb0TXXXXXX
```

You can get the Teams UserId by either:

1. [Querying the roster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57499608/10860086), or
2. Having the user message the bot, and setting a breakpoint on an incoming message, looking at the `Activity.ChannelData` for the Teams userId, or
3. Dynamically build a static dictionary of all incoming messages that stores the user's email mapped to their Teams userId (I believe both are found in `Activity.ChannelData`).

*Note: #1 and #2 both require a user to message the bot, first, which sort of defeats the purpose of proactive messages*

After you have the appropriate Teams IDs, you just [send a proactive message to a Teams user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120193/how-can-my-teams-bot-start-a-new-11-chat-with-a-known-user/57150951#57150951). The end of this link also mentions `trustServiceUrl`, which you may find handy if you run into permissions/auth issues when trying to send a proactive message.

Comment: Thank you. But, I've been unable to query the roster. My bot echo's input in the "Conversation" tab in teams correctly. But, when I try to query the roster, the `Team` property is null. I used this line: `var members = (await turnContext.TurnState.Get<IConnectorClient>().Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(
    turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>().Team.Id).ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();` shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57120193/how-can-my-teams-bot-start-a-new-11-chat-with-a-known-user/57150951#57150951)

Comment: Did you add the bot to a team? `Teams > App Studio > Manifest Editor > YourBot > Test and Distribute > Install > [Dropdown by Add] Add to a team`?

Comment: I did not add the app to a team. I did however install the Teams app in Teams. I'm looking for a way to use just a Teams app without creating an actual team in Teams.

Comment: @ZachTempleton You can't do that because the bot won't have appropriate scope. This is to prevent spam.